# Change the color of strings affected by regex on (document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I what I'm trying to accomplish here, is to change the color of words affected by some regex.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  container = $("#modal_container section").text();
  hashtags = /\#\w+/g;
  var container_hash = container.match(hashtags);
  $(container_hash).css({'color':'red'}); 
  //We're grabbing the words, but how can I change the color?
  alert(container_hash);

 });
```

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vuDzC/2/ to make it more clear.

Thanks

Comment: You can't change the colour of individual words in the sense of arbitrarily selecting some of an element's text. You'd need to wrap each word in, say, span elements, and then change the colour of each span.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't change color of textNodes/texts, you should wrap the matching text with an element and then style that element.

```
$("#modal_container section p").html(function(_, html) {
   return html.replace(/(\#\w+)/g, '<span class="red">$1</span>');   
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vuDzC/4/

Comment: Thanks, this does the job. But, what does the $1 inside the span means? I'm just curious...

Comment: @Aaron You are welcome, that refers to the strings that has been selected by the pattern within the first `()` in regex.

Comment: much more graceful than mine .. saving for future reference :)

Answer (score 1):

This sort of does that you're looking for (or should be a good enough example):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var text = $("#modal_container").html();
        var myRegExp = new RegExp('\\#\\w+','gi');
        var newtext = text.replace(myRegExp,'<span style="color:red;">$&</span>');
        $("#empty").html(newtext);
    });
</script>
<div id="modal_container">
    #works<br />
    # Desnt Work<br />
    Not Even Close<br />
</div>
<div id="empty" style="margin-top:30px;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(function(){

  var container = $("#modal_container section");
  var htmlWrappedHashtags = container.html().replace(/\(#\w+)/g, '<span class="red">$1</span>');
  container.html(htmlWrappedHashtags);

  $(".red").css({'color':'red'}); // or better: include ".red {color: red;}" into your CSS

 });
```

Comment: This also works, but I accepted the previous answer. Good answer though :)

Comment: @Aaron: yeah, I was slower. The previous answer also has a fiddle and a text explanation, so it's fair :)