# Replace a string with the highlighted string by matching it to Regular Expression in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, highlight

I have Array of Regular Expression(keys) and I want all the strings matching the regular expression to get highlighted by a particular color without changing their display value.

```
    //sel_data is the blob of text to be processed
   //keys is the array of regular expression

     for (i=0;i<k.length;i++){
     var data=keys[i];

     var re = new RegExp(data,"g");

     //pat_data[keys[i]][0]["id"] is the corresponding value of the regular expression to be associated with the highlighted text.

     var re_str="<em class='highlight'  value="+ pat_data[keys[i]][0]["id"]+">"+"</em>"
     var rep_data=sel_data.replace(re,re_str);
     //alert (rep_data);
     sel_data=rep_data;
 }
```

Now the problem here is that I am ending up replacing text's display text by the regular expression itself . But I want all the strings matching the regular expression to get highlighted by a particular color and their value to get changed (this color and value will be associated and stored with the regular expression in some way) without changing the display text/value.

Ex. if sel_data = "I got 91.2 percentage", and the regular expression is '\d+', then it should just highlight '91.2' and change the value field of this text as something associated with the given regular expression.

It can be achieved by getting the matches one by one(like it is done ib ruby) and then process it but I am not getting how to achieve it.

It would be great if anybody could help me in this. Thanks in advance.

P.S I am very new to javascript.

Comment: I think [this topic][1] may help you with what you want to achieve.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28154276/how-to-replace-emoticons-yet-after-user-write-text-and-press-space

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question correctly. You can´t change the color of textnodes/text. What you can do is to replace the match with an element and give this element a specific css-class. Take a look in the answer of this question.

[Change the color of strings affected by regex on (document).ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126123/change-the-color-of-strings-affected-by-regex-on-document-ready)